# Set visalbe border to matrix in XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I have a matrix-like structure. Each row is a LinearLayout of n-TextViews. Both are created programmatically and added to a LinearLayout "container". In XML:

```
<LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how it looks in App after building a matrix at runtime:

[image]

I always want to add a border to first/last column as well as to the first and second row, for each mxn-matrix. I want it to look like this:

[image]

I think the border / frame has to be added programmatically as well. 
So my approach would be something like building a TableLayout as container and replace the LinearLayouts for each row with TableRows. 
After that set the background color of TableLayout to black and give every needed TextView a padding on the right place programmatically.

But this seems to be a very stressful task. So I really hope there is a better way to do that.

I am using Kotlin.

I am very thankful for every suggestion!

Comment: check this,https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-use-tablelayout-in-android.html

Comment: I solved the problem as I described earlier by setting the container's background to black and margin on the appropriate TextViews.
Probably not the most beautiful solution, but also not the worst.
If someone has a better way to do it, I would appreciate hearing about it :)